# white color become transparent in android

Tags: android

I have a strange problem.
  I found that if i use #FFFFFF or #FFF or #FFFFFFFF. Sometimes it will be white in phone,but sometimes it will be transparent.
  If you change #FFFFFF to other color , it will be normal.
  And I found that the strange problem usually happen in the first time to start my app.And if I quit the app ,everything will be ok.
  The problem happens in all activities.
  I test some phone,only one phone will happen this problem. And this problem will happen when i first time to install,but when i second time to install,it will be ok.

Comment: What do you mean by "translation"?

Comment: Do you know the meaning of translation in android?

Comment: What you ask unclear is (Yoda).

Comment: sorry English is my second language. ”translation“ is "transparent"

Comment: Maybe it could be linked to the theme your are using in style.xml. ..

Comment: What is the one phone? What OS version does it have?